# Shell script to download and extract a tarball from GitHub

Tags: shell, sh

I don't want anything to execute if any preceding step fails:

```
#!/bin/sh

file="v0.9"
renamed=$file".tar.gz"
dir="utils/external/firepython/"
location="https://github.com/darwin/firepython/tarball/$file"

wget --no-check-certificate $location --output-document=$renamed && \
mkdir -p $dir && \
gunzip $renamed && \
echo "extracting to $dir" && \
tar xf $file".tar" --directory $dir --strip-components 1 && \
echo "Cleaning up..." && \
rm -r $file".tar" && \
echo "Done"
```

Comment: If you use tar -zxf it will gunzip the file for you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're looking for `set -e`. From [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/set.html):

> `-e`
>   When this option is on, if a simple command fails for any of the reasons listed in [Consequences of Shell Errors](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_08_01) or returns an exit status value >0, and is not part of the compound list following a while, until, or if keyword, and is not a part of an AND or OR list, and is not a pipeline preceded by the ! reserved word, then the shell shall immediately exit.

In other words, plain commands cause the shell to exit if they fail. (You can use something like `command || true` to allow `command` to return nonzero.) If you need to perform some cleanup, you can set a trap for the `EXIT` pseudo-signal.

And better double-quote all your variable expansions. That way your script won't fail horribly if you ever point it at a directory or an URL containing `?` or `*` or a space.

```
dry -r
wget --no-check-certificate "$location" --output-document="$renamed"
mkdir -p "$dir"
gunzip "$renamed"
echo "extracting to $dir"
tar xf "$file.tar" --directory "$dir" --strip-components 1
echo "Cleaning up..."
rm -r "$file.tar"
echo "Done"
```

---

Another useful shell idiom to pass optional arguments to a shell script without hassle is to set variables only if they're unset. That way you can pass arguments through the environment, e.g. `file=v0.9.1 myscript`.

```
: "${file=v0.9}"
: "${renamed=$file.tar.gz}"
: "${dir=utils/external/firepython/}"
: "${location=https://github.com/darwin/firepython/tarball/$file}"
```

Answer (score 8):

@Gilles answer about `set -e` is right on target. An alternative way if only one or two commands in a script are must-haves, you can use `important-command || exit` as a way to drop out of the script if any one command fails.

I often include an auxilary function in my scripts called 'flunk' that handles any cleanup that needs to be done if something fails. It might look something like this:

```
function flunk () {
    echo "SCRIPT FAILED: $1"
    rm $TMPFILES
    exit 1
}

command
important-command || flunk "Could not do X"
command
```

Comment: I was actually wondering about failure scenarios like that, but held back since that was outside the scope of the question.

Comment: @Tshepang: For most tasks, I prefer to program defensively: return an error code if there's anything suspicious. So failing commands abort the script, and only specifically-vetted commands are allowed to fail. Caleb's approach is right in cases where there's a very important command you want to execute, and its preparatory steps are optional; that's not the case here.

Comment: The other thing that I don't think you can do with just having `set -e` is handling cleanup if there are things you need to do if a command fails. For example in my backup scripts I often have mounts. If something goes wrong with the backup process, I still want the end of the script to run that cleanly unmounts the drives. Putting each of those aspects in functions, then using a flunk function like above allows you to do any cleanup you want before the script closes even when your important-command bombed for some reason.

Answer (score 6):

You are probably may use pipe instead of creating and deleting downloaded file:

```
mkdir -p "$dir"
echo "extracting to $dir"
wget --no-check-certificate "$location" --output-document=- |
    tar zxvf - --strip-components 1 --directory="$dir"
echo "Done"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes using && or || can induce a race condition, so it may be better to rewrite this with if statements instead, as I do not see at a glance why exit status with the one-liner/"pipeline" approach is not doing it for you...  And you can always test if the extracted files are present with like `test -f "dir/whatever.file" || exit 1` or something.

Comment: Could you provide justification or a citation to back up your remark about possible race conditions?

Comment: TBH I am not entirely sure. This is just some advice that an old posix savy friend gave me. I was hoping someone might ask this because I am not entirely sure and would like to know more myself. However, I do think it's better to use `if ; then; else` in general. Some pitfalls can be avoided. Please see : http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cmd1_.26.26_cmd2_.7C.7C_cmd3

Answer (score 0):

Just a reminder, these kind of scripts sometimes tend to fail if  wget or gunzip is not installed. This might happen in some minimal installations.

Comment: If `wget` or `gunzip` are not installed, it will not *tend to fail*, but certainly fail ;-)

Comment: Agreed, it's a  good idea to check the existence of whatever your script depends on. `if ! gunzip -V >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then { echo gunzip not found;exit 1 ;} ;else { do_whatever ;} ; fi`